# "Don't cry" or "Don't you cry"

Tags: grammar

"Don't cry." is universally accepted sentence form. But I also notice some books also provide "Don't you cry." Both means "not to cry". Are they all correct?

Comment: Yes. Although the implication of "don't you cry" is usually "or I'll cry too".

Comment: Interestingly, the Guns'n Roses song [Don't Cry](http://www.metrolyrics.com/dont-cry-lyrics-guns-n-roses.html) contains "don't you cry" as a lyric more than it does just "don't cry"

Comment: At least in song use, the beats being covered by that section of the lyrics are a potentially significant factor. In the Psychedelic Furs' song "India," for example, the meter would be ruined if the singer simply sang "India-ha, don't cry"; the actual phrase "don't you cry" lands on a succession of three descending notes and punctuates the emotion more powerfully.

Comment: The imperative in English speech almost always omits the implied subject pronoun [you]. *[You] halt, right now!* Negative imperatives often begin with *don't* and the implied second person pronoun is still there. *Don't [you] do it!*

Answer (score 4):

*Don't **you** cry* can have several meanings.

It can mean, no, not *you* (maybe, too?)

> "There — don't you cry no more. I can't abear to see you cry." He was blinking himself.

or, emphasizing an imperative

> Your daddy's rich/ And your mamma's good lookin'/ So hush little baby/ Don't you cry.

or, just a gentle personalizing and softening of the imperative.

> Hush, little baby, don't you cry, Mamma's gonna sing you a lullabye

Comment: Yes, the reason why I asked this question is I listened to guns n' roses' song. interesting.